# Problems with initializing a 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript

Thats my Code
I am trying to make a grade system.
Gusenbauer should be the array place for pupils and 1ahitm for example his class
I am from java and these arrays here confuse me.
what do i need to do to make something like noten[pupil][class]=grade; possible?
Also my document.notenformular.name.value is undefined, any ideas why?

```
  var noten = new Array();
    noten["Gusenbauer"] = new Array();
    noten["Gusenbauer"]["1ahitm"] = 0;
    noten["seppl"]["1ahitm"] = new Array();
    noten["seppl"]["1ahitm"] = 0;
    noten["leo"]["1ahitm"] = new Array();
    noten["leo"]["1ahitm"] = 0;
    noten["Gussenbauer"]["2ahitm"] = new Array();
    noten["Gussenbauer"]["2ahitm"] = 0;
    noten["steiner"]["2ahitm"] = new Array();
    noten["steiner"]["2ahitm"] = 0;
    noten["roland"]["2ahitm"] = new Array();
    noten["roland"]["2ahitm"] = 0;
    alert(noten["roland"]["2ahitm"]);
    alert("was");
function noteEintragen() {
        var name = document.notenformular.name.value;
        alert(name);
        var note = document.notenformular.note.value;
        var klasse = document.notenformular.klasse.value;

        noten[name][klasse] = note;


    }
ody>
<div id="wrapper">

    <h1>Name - Noteneintragung - Klassenspiegel</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Klasse auswählen, Name auswählen, Note eintragen</p>
    <form name="notenformular">
        Klasse
        <br>
        <select name="klasse" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" size="20" tabindex="2">
            <option value="1ahitm">1ahitm</option>
            <option value="2ahitm">1bhitm</option>

        </select>
        <br>
        <br> Name
        <br>
        <div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
            <select name="name" id="test" size="20" tabindex="1">
                <option value="Gusenbauer">Gusenbauer</option>
                <option value="seppl">seppl</option>
                <option value="leo">leo</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use javascript object to store your values

```
noten = {
    "Gusenbauer" :{
        "1ahitm" : 0,
        "2ahitm": 0
    },
    "seppl" :{
        "1ahitm" : 0
    },
    "steiner" :{
        "2ahitm" : 0
    },
    "roland" :{
        "2ahitm" : 0
    }
};
```

now you can use square bracket notation to access values from noten object.

noten["roland"]["2ahitm"]; //0

Comment: Ok, but can i , if you look further down, do noten[pupil][class]= note? And do you have any idea why note.value is undefined. Also can i still use for in loops? because i need to acces them to print them for example                             Edit: oh and thanks by the way :)

Comment: you need to do that in two statements. noten[pupil] = {};  noten[pupil][class] = note;

Comment: But why? Why do i need empty {}  I am sorry, this is a bit complicated for me. So if i wanted to increase the object to 3, would it then be noten[pupil] = {}; noten[subject] ={}; noten[pupil][class][subject]= 2;

Comment: And can i still loop them? Since they are Strings how would i go through for example all pupils of 1ahitm

Comment: yes you can iterate JavaScript object. check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in